# Distribution of sample skewness and kurtosis

Tags: probability

I am working on my thesis right now and I'm almost done with it, but just on the last step I encountered some problems with a proof.

I have an independent sample $X_{1}, ..., X_{n}$ that follows the normal distribution $N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$. Now I have to find the distribution of:

1) the skewness: $\frac{\hat{\mu}_{3}}{\sigma^{3}}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{3}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{3}$ and

2) the kurtosis $\frac{\hat{\mu}_{4}}{\sigma^{4}}=\frac{1}{\sigma^{4}}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{4}$.

I already thought that it would help to write it out e.g. as

$\hat{\mu}_{3}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}^{3}-3X_{i}^{2}\overline{X} +3X_{i}\overline{X}^{2}+\overline{X}^{3})$ and then try to derive the proof with such ideas like a) $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is normally distributed and b) that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sigma}(X_{i}-\overline{X})$ is standard normally distributed, such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sigma^{2}}(X_{i}-\overline{X})^{2}$ converges against the $\chi^{2}$-distribution with $n-1$ degrees of freedom, that on the other hand is normally distributed for $n\to\infty$.

But I cannot put the this ideas together to derive the proof.

I am really almost desperate....So I would appreciate any help and ideas so much.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/100850/closed-form-expression-for-the-distribution-of-the-sample-kurtosis-of-gaussian-d

Comment: There are divisions missing that would stabilize the central moments with increasing $n$